# How to get the id for second tbody?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table id="notificationTable">
    <tbody id="bindNotification">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody id="titleNotification" style="position:fixed; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-3px;">
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For the first tbody that is bindNotification I can get the id by using `document.getElementById("bindNotification ");`

But for the second tbody that is the titleNotification I use the same method to get the id but its null.
Is there any other way to retrieve the ID?

Comment: So... how about `document.getElementById("titleNotification");`?

Comment: `document.getElementById("titleNotification")` is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/c8a2fgna/

Comment: Don't use tables for layout - tables should be used for tabular data only (I'm guessing this is not an email template as you are using js on it)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let x = document.getElementById("titleNotification");
alert(x);
```

```html
<table id="notificationTable">
  <tbody id="bindNotification">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody id="titleNotification" style="position:fixed; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-3px;">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```